# Sitecore | Unable to set extranet\anonymous user details through code behind

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We have a subscription form with 3 fields(Email, Phone number, Interests) displayed for anonymous users. When we click subscribe we need to save those details to extranet\anonymous users.

Form Looks like [Subscription Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOpmT.png)

Below is the code I am using:

```cs
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var userProfile = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile;
            userProfile.FullName = "Anonymous";
            userProfile.ProfileItemId = "{C7E512C3-D10D-4EE7-A9D1-52474E858456}";
            userProfile.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            userProfile.SetCustomProperty("Phone Number", txtPhone.Text);
            userProfile.SetCustomProperty("Interests", ddlInterests.SelectedItem.Text);
            userProfile.Save();
        }
        catch (System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = GetDictionaryText("Unable to register");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting An exception of type 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException' occurred in Sitecore.Kernel.dll but was not handled in user code.

Please see below screen shot for exception:

[Exception while assigning values/profile id to extranet\anonymous user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp95r.png)

Can someone please suggest what could be the issue and how to assign details to anonymous user?

Comment: The error might be due to user rights (your current user not having enough rights to write to the profile) or some protection in Sitecore (as you would never want to write to the anynomous profile). Why would you want to write that info to the anonymous user profile??

Comment: @Gatogordo I want to write that info to anonymous user profile to track user details and anonymous user interests and personalize content occordingly

Comment: You should use the contact and not the user for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning this information to the anonymous user is a bad idea because the user is shared over all anonymous sessions. Unless you are using actual users (or maybe virtual users), the good way to do this is to use the Sitecore Contact. More information can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/contacts) (and related pages).

It comes down to using `Tracker.Current.Contact` instead of `Sitecore.Context.User`.

Comment: I am now able track anonymous user information using sitecore contact. 

I have one more question i.e., we are saving users inetrests(Bikes, Cars) in sitecore contact and saved information is visible in mongo db, In experience profile we can just see anonymous user details like email, phone number and personal information. Is there a way we can even  see interests in experience profile?

Comment: Data from your Mongo will (should) flow to the experience database but this process can take a while - it's not instant. Showing custom data (facets) in the Sitecore admin will require some customization.

Comment: Could you please let me know what customization's must done?

Comment: There are several blogs about this, e.g. http://reyrahadian.com/2016/08/27/sitecore-8-extending-experience-profile-part-2-displaying-contact-facet-simple-properties/